# How to hide/show iPhone settings?

Tags: iphone, settings, hide, show

i have an app , the option of purchase is to show settings(Root.plist settings). Question is how to programmatically(or maybe another something) hide/shows this settings ?

Or how to hide some of options in settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the settings visible in the Settings.app? If so, it's not possible to change them programatically, nor can you switch between "sets" of options. Your only option really is to only have the settings inside the app itself.